# Qt: Separate input and display on new lines

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qmessagebox

I am trying to get a user to type in an address that is comma delimited. The idea is that the program will display the address in a correct format on new lines. I am new to using Qt Creator. I am trying to convert the input to a list and then display the list in a `QMessageBox`.

The error I am faced with is:

```
C:\Qt\5.11.2\mingw53_32\include\QtCore\qstring.h:275: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from '`QStringList`' to '`qlonglong`' (aka '`long long`') for 1st argument
```

and

```
C:\Users\Nickitaes\Desktop\Misc\UNISA\COS2614\Assignment 01\header\main.cpp:25: error: no matching conversion for functional-style cast from 'QStringList' to '`QString`'
```

Below is my code. I'm not sure where I am going wrong and the documentation I have found uses integers.

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QMessageBox msgBox;
    QString enteredAddress = QInputDialog::getText(0, "User Address",
                                                 "Enter address each field separated by a comma "
                                                 "and a space: ");
    QStringList lines = enteredAddress.split(",/n ");

    QString response = QString("The new address format is ").arg(lines);
    msgBox.setText("Message Box", + QString(enteredAddress.split(",/n")))

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't expect answers to do your homework in the future: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple typos in your code: e.g., `"Message Box", +` should be `"Message Box" +`.
Here's a good starting point:

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QString enteredAddress = QInputDialog::getText(
        0,
        "User Address",
        "Enter address each field separated by a comma and a space: ");
    QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.setText("Message Box:\n" + enteredAddress.replace(", ", "\n"));
    msgBox.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```